# Many-to-one unidirectional association: delete parent and set children column to null

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, many-to-one

I have two Java classes, Document and Category.

Document.java

```
public class Document {
    private int document_id;
    private Category category;

    public void setDocument_id(int document_id) {
        this.document_id = document_id;
    }

    public int getDocument_id() {
        return this.document_id;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return this.category;
    }
}
```

Category.java

```
public class Category {
    private int category_id;
    private String description;

    public void setCategory_id(int category_id){
        this.category_id = category_id;
    }
    public int getCategory_id(){
        return this.category_id;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }
```

As you can see, each Document can have zero or one category; for this reason, I wrote two Hibernate mapping files.

Document.hbm.xml

```
[...]
<many-to-one name="category" class="Category" column="category"/>
[...]
```

and nothing, except its properties, in Category.hbm.xml.

When a Category is deleted (`session.delete(category)`) I'd like that the corresponding column on Document is updated with a "null" value, but with this configuration I obtain

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible in Hibernate: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596708/hibernate-manytoone-remove-entry-at-one-side-set-fk-to-null-at-many-side

Comment: Did you set cascade mode for this relation?

Comment: No, I didn't set any cascade mode because if I delete a Document nothing should happen to Categories, but if I delete a Category all Documents with that Category should have `category=null`.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate associations are all inherently unidirectional. As far as Hibernate is concerned, the association from `Document to Category` is a different association than the association from `Category to Document` (if there is any) .

As there is no association defined from `Category to Document`, the changes made to the `Category` end of the association will not set the `Category` in `Document` to null. This is expected, because Hibernate is not known about the containment of `Category` in `Document`.

So, the solution to this is to get all the `documents` which are mapped to the `Category` you want to delete, set the `category` of those documents to null and the delete the `Category`. Its like before deleting the category, you are deleting all the references to that category.